# Laravel upload image to storage on windows

Tags: php, laravel

For development im working on windows on my laravel project.
Im trying to get file uploads working locally.

My upload code:

```
public function addPicture(Request $request, $id)
{
    $bathroom = Bathroom::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    $validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'afbeelding' => 'required|image|dimensions:min_width=400,min_height=400',
    ]);
    if($validatedData->fails())
    {
        return Response()->json([
            "success" => false,
            "errors" => $validatedData->errors()
        ]);
    }
    if ($file = $request->file('afbeelding')) {
        $img = Image::make($file);
        $img->resize(3000, 3000, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });
        $img->stream();
        $uid = Str::uuid();
        $fileName = Str::slug($bathroom->name . $uid).'.jpg';

        $this->createImage($img, 3000, "high", $bathroom->id, $fileName);
        $this->createImage($img, 1000, "med", $bathroom->id, $fileName);
        $this->createImage($img, 700, "thumb", $bathroom->id, $fileName);
        $this->createImage($img, 400, "small", $bathroom->id, $fileName);

        $picture = new Picture();
        $picture->url = '-';
        $picture->priority = '99';
        $picture->alt = Str::limit($bathroom->description,100);
        $picture->margin = 0;
        $picture->path = $fileName;
        $picture->bathroom_id = $id;
        $picture->save();

        return Response()->json([
            "success" => true,
            "image" => asset('/storage/img/bathroom/'.$id.'/small/'.$fileName),
            "id" => $picture->id
        ]);
    }
    return Response()->json([
        "success" => false,
        "image" => ''
    ]);
}

public function createImage($img, $size, $quality, $bathroomId, $fileName){
    $img->resize($size, $size, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
        $constraint->upsize();
    });
    Storage::put(  $this->getUploadPath($bathroomId, $fileName, $quality), $img->stream('jpg',100));

}

public function  getUploadPath($bathroom_id, $filename, $quality = 'high'){
    $returnPath = asset('/storage/img/bathroom/'.$bathroom_id.'/'.$quality.'/'.$filename);
    echo $returnPath;

}
```

I did run: php artisan storage:link

And the following path is available `D:\Documents\repos\projectname\storage\app`. When I upload a file I get:

> "message": "fopen(D:\Documents\repos\projectname\storage\app\):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory",
> "exception": "ErrorException",
> "file": "D:\Documents\repos\projectname\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php",
> "line": 157,

And later on in the log:

```
 "file": "D:\\Documents\\repos\\projectname\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin\\BathroomController.php",
        "line": 141, .
```

which points to the following line.

```
Storage::put(  $this->getUploadPath($bathroomId, $fileName, $quality), $img->stream('jpg',100));
```

of the createImage function.
How can I make it work on windows so that I can test my website locally?

Comment: What return `$img->stream('jpg',100)`?

Comment: Does anything happen if you remove the trailing `/` from the path?

Answer (score 0):

I usually save images to public folder directly here is a working code from one of my projects

```
 $category = new Categories;
//get icon path and moving it
$iconName = time().'.'.request()->icon->getClientOriginalExtension();
 // the icon in the line above indicates to the name of the icon's field in 
 //front-end
$icon_path = '/public/category/icon/'.$iconName;
//actually moving the icon to its destination
request()->icon->move(public_path('/category/icon/'), $iconName);  
$category->icon = $icon_path;
//save the image path to db 
$category->save();
return redirect('/category/index')->with('success' , 'Category Stored Successfully');
```

with some modifications to fit your code it should work correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue and have solved it in the following manner

In order to upload the file to any path follow these steps.

Create a new disk in `config/filesystem.php` and point it to any path you like e.g to `D:/test` or whatever

```
'disks' => [

    // ...

     'archive' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => 'D:/test',
         ],

    // ...
```

Remember `archive` is the disk name you can tweak it to whatever.
After that do `config:cache`

then to upload file to the specifed directory do something like

```
  $request->file("image_file_identifier")->storeAs('SubFolderName', 'fileName', 'Disk');
```

e.g

```
  $request->file("image_file")->storeAs('images', 'aa.jpg', 'archive');
```

Now to get the file use following code

```
      $path = 'D:\test\images\aa.jpg';



    if (!\File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = \File::get($path);
    $type = \File::mimeType($path);

    $response = \Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
```

Comment: "In order to upload the file to another drive of windows other that storage folder follow these steps." I want to upload the file to stroage.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart ya then give that path in `config file`

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart like ```'disks' => [

    // ...

     'archive' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => 'D:/Documents/repos/projectname/storage/app',
         ],```

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart i have updated my answer hope that will help  you , the method is same whatever path you specify uploads  will be save their

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Image Intervention here. If not, you can run the command:

```
      composer require intervention/image
```

This will install intervention on your project. Now use the following code to upload images locally.

You can call the function to save images this way:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
   $image = $request->file('image');
   //Define upload path
   $destinationPath = public_path('/storage/img/bathroom/');//this will be created inside public folder
   $filename = round(microtime(true) * 1000) . "." .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

  //upload file
  $this->uploadFile($image,$destinationPath,$filename,300,300);

//put your code to Save In Database
//just save the $filename in the db. 

//put your return statements here    


}

    


public function  uploadFile($file,$destinationPath,$filename,$height=null,$width=null){
    
//create folder if does not exist
if (!File::exists($destinationPath)){
   File::makeDirectory($destinationPath, 0777, true, true);
}
    
//Resize the image before upload using Image        Intervention
            
if($height!=null && $width!=null){
   $image_resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
   $image_resize->resize($width, $height);
   //Upload the resized image to the project path
   $image_resize->save($destinationPath.$filename);
}else{
     //upload the original image without resize. 
     $file->move($destinationPath,$filename);
     }
}
```

If you anyways want to use the Storage Facade,I have modified your code by using Image->resize()->encode() before using the Storage::put(). Please see if the following code works. (Sorry, I got not time to test)

```
public function addPicture(Request $request, $id)
{
  $bathroom = Bathroom::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
  $validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'afbeelding' =>'required|image|dimensions:min_width=400,min_height=400']);
if($validatedData->fails())
{
    return Response()->json([
        "success" => false,
        "errors" => $validatedData->errors()
    ]);
}
if ($file = $request->file('afbeelding')) {
    $img = Image::make($file);
    $img->resize(3000, 3000, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
        $constraint->upsize();
    });
    //Encode the image if you want to use Storage::put(),this is important step
    $img->encode('jpg',100);//default quality is 90,i passed 100
    $uid = Str::uuid();
    $fileName = Str::slug($bathroom->name . $uid).'.jpg';

    $this->createImage($img, 3000, "high", $bathroom->id, $fileName);
    $this->createImage($img, 1000, "med", $bathroom->id, $fileName);
    $this->createImage($img, 700, "thumb", $bathroom->id, $fileName);
    $this->createImage($img, 400, "small", $bathroom->id, $fileName);

    $picture = new Picture();
    $picture->url = '-';
    $picture->priority = '99';
    $picture->alt = Str::limit($bathroom->description,100);
    $picture->margin = 0;
    $picture->path = $fileName;
    $picture->bathroom_id = $id;
    $picture->save();

    return Response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "image" => asset('/storage/img/bathroom/'.$id.'/small/'.$fileName),
        "id" => $picture->id
    ]);
}
return Response()->json([
    "success" => false,
    "image" => ''
]);
}
  public function createImage($img, $size, $quality, $bathroomId,$fileName){
$img->resize($size, $size, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    $constraint->upsize();
});
Storage::put(  $this->getUploadPath($bathroomId, $fileName, $quality), $img);

}
public function  getUploadPath($bathroom_id, $filename, $quality ='high'){
$returnPath = asset('/storage/img/bathroom/'.$bathroom_id.'/'.$quality.'/'.$filename);
return $returnPath; //changed echo to return

}
```

Source used: [Intervention repo,Github](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php#L146)

Also, please note that The **put** method of Storage **works with the Image Intervention output** whereas the **putFile** method **works with both the  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as well as Illuminate\Http\File and instances.**

Comment: I am using image intervation, but my goal is to use the laravel storage facade.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart I have updated my answer if you want to use Storage facade. Please check if it works. I have not tested the code.

Answer (score -1):

i recomended use features from laravel Storage that's simple for any upload